# php for loop to compare values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a for loop that checks numbers stored in a database.
The data is stored as a string and then split in php.
The code below should only return the amount of stock for that that size. It looks as though it should work.
The data is stored in the database like this:

size,quantity_*_size,quantity: and so on

I start by splitting the array:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
$sizes = explode('_*_',$result['sizes']);
```

Pretty straight foreward, this is then lopped through and split

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($sizes); $x){
    $current_size = explode(',',$sizes[$x]);
    if($size === (int)$current_size[1]){
        $stock = $current_size[1];
           //do something with matched data
           $x = count($sizes);
        }else{
           $x++;
        }
}
```

But it doesn't ever match the data.
I've been at this for hours now and I've got nothing.
This is the whole thing:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
    $sizes = explode('_*_',$result['sizes']);
    //check stock of each size
    $size = (int)substr($size,6,2); //origal string from POST Size :x
    $stock = 0;
        for($x = 0; $x < count($sizes); $x){
        $current_size = explode(',',$sizes[$x]);
        echo $size.'='.$current_size[1].'.';
        if($size === (int)$current_size[1]){
            $stock = $current_size[1];
            echo 'found it';
            $x = count($sizes);
        }else{
            $x++;
        }
        echo $size.'='.$current_size[1].'    ';
    }
    echo $stock;
```

If it helps this is the data from the database as its stored:
4,10_**6,14**_8,0_**10,3**_12,0_*_14,2

data is formated to match the explode function but its changed in here.

Comment: looks to me like `$size` is never initialized. first appearance is `$size = (int)substr($size,6,2);` the variable is treated as empty string as the function argument, then `0` after the cast

Comment: it is further up $size = mysql_real_ecape($_POST['size'];

Comment: ok. I don't 100% follow the intent, but I think you'd likely get more help, and make things clearer for yourself, if you inserted a few `print_r`s or `var_dump`s (after the explodes would be a good starT)

Comment: I have actually found it now I missed a < in my html form, so the data wasn't sending or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand size should be in $current_size[0], not $current_size[1] like in your code.

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);
$sizes = explode('_*_',$result['sizes']);
//check stock of each size
$size = (int)substr($size,6,2); //origal string from POST Size :x
$stock = 0;
    for($x = 0; $x < count($sizes); $x){
    $current_size = explode(',',$sizes[$x]);
    echo $size.'='.$current_size[0].'.';
    if($size === (int)$current_size[0]){
        $stock = $current_size[1];
        echo 'found it';
        $x = count($sizes);
    }else{
        $x++;
    }
    echo $size.'='.$current_size[0].'    ';
}
echo $stock;
```

Comment: wow that was a stupid mistake, I mentioned earlier in a comment that I thought I solved it. Nope this did the trick. I was comparing the size with the quantity. Unfortunately for me I hadn't noticed.

Comment: sweet, I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

you have the three `=` operator in your `if` statement

```
if($size === (int)$current_size[1]){
```

i don't know if using only two (`==`) instead would change anything. if not you could try to add the cast to (int) also for the `$size` variable

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely to be the [strict comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) you're using in your `if` statement:

```
if($size === (int)$current_size[1]){
```

You've said in your comment:

```
$size = mysql_real_ecape($_POST['size']); // assumed this is a typo in your comment not code
```

Chances are, `$size` will be coming out of `$_POST` and `mysql_real_escape_string` (deprecated, use `mysqli`) as a **string**, and you're comparing it to an integer.

... strict comparison operators compare variable **type** as well as contents, so you're saying this in pseudo:

```
if( [string - size] is equal to [int - current size] )
```

So try this:

```
if((int)$size === (int)$current_size[1]){ // cast $size as integer also
```

...or

```
if($size == $current_size[1]){ // type juggle while comparing
```